# How to assign css to google plus share button in iframe?

Tags: css, button, iframe, share

I have a problem with the CSS of my share button.  The style of Google resets my CSS.
This is my iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://apis.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&amp;size=tall&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.infomovies.it%2Flocale.aspx%3Flocale%3D1&amp;gsrc=3p&amp;ic=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.it.C5yhGIzSUtg.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Fz%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAItRSTNNChyVUYjljlut1Guvhr2Y24lHpw#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Conload&amp;id=I0_1395148139488&amp;parent=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=39693034"></iframe>
```

This is my script:

```
<script>
$('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('head').append($('<link/>', { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/masterBlaster.css', type: 'text/css' }));
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit css (or anything else) within an iframe.